Shadow Artifacts in viewport
I have these weird shadow artifacts on my mesh in solid, material and rendered preview. The mesh is not shaded smooth and all UV's have been manually cleaned up. All faces are also quads or tri's.


Those look very much, almost exactly, like shadows from a point light that is near the top of the model. Did you not want shadows to be shown in the viewport?

hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

@Phrogz there shouldn't be any light affecting the mesh in this mode and the shadows make no sense for that.

I seem to be able to fix it by removing the principled BSDF between the image texture and the output but I need to know why it makes a difference

@moonboots this should be the blender file Drive link

For some reason your split normals (the normals that determine the shading) are messed up (it happens with imported fbx for example), to fix that go into the Data panel > Geometry Data > click on Clear Custom Split Normals Data:

